# org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "oci"

Tags: python, hadoop, pyspark, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

When I am trying to access file stored in OCI object storage using pySpark as shown below , I am hitting above error.

```
import configparser
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import os
import io
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import sql_queries as sql
import pandas as pd
import oci
from oci.config import validate_config ## To validate configuration
from oci.object_storage import ObjectStorageClient ## To work with object storage
```

### To read OCI files

```
 spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .config("spark.hadoop.fs.oci.client.hostname", 'https://objectstorage.ap-hyderabad-1.oraclecloud.com')\
        .config("spark.hadoop.fs.oci.client.regionCodeOrId", 'ap-hyderabad-1')\
        .config('spark.hadoop.fs.oci.client.auth.tenantId', 'ocid1.tenancy.oc1..xxxx')\
        .config('spark.hadoop.fs.oci.client.auth.userId', 'ocid1.user.oc1..xxxx')\
        .config('spark.hadoop.fs.oci.client.auth.fingerprint', '01:87:82:6f:4f:c3:af:fd:9c:ce:c4:fd:47:f8:7a:aa') \
        .config('spark.hadoop.fs.oci.client.auth.pemfilepath', '/Users/xxxx/.oci/oci_api_key_private.pem') \
        .config("spark.jars", "/Users/xxxx/oci-hdfs/lib/oci-hdfs-full-2.9.2.1.jar")\
        .getOrCreate()
    
    nycrime_df = spark.read.csv("oci://udacity-cap-bs/NY_Crimes_2016.csv",header=True,inferSchema=True)
```

Comment: Error :

    21/12/28 19:50:02 WARN FileStreamSink: Assume no metadata directory. Error while looking for metadata directory in the path: oci://udacity-cap-bs/NY_Crimes_2016.csv.
    org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "oci"

Comment: After adding relevant driver to $SPARK_HOME/jars ..this error is resolved ..but I am seeing different error now for below :
         nycrime_df = spark.read.csv("oci://udacity-cap- 
         bsz@axbnhx1546i6/AB_NYC_2019.csv",header=True,inferSchema=True)

Comment: Error:
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o89.csv.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/openssl/EncryptionException
 at com.oracle.bmc.http.signing.internal.DefaultRequestSignerFactory.createKeySupplier(DefaultRequestSignerFactory.java:108)
 at com.oracle.bmc.http.signing.internal.DefaultRequestSignerFactory.createRequestSigner(DefaultRequestSignerFactory.java:53)

Comment: Hi - please update your main question to express the current issue you are facing. Right now your post is about an issue you have resolved, and the different, current issue you are hitting is only mentioned in the comments

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the classpath is missing the JARs for bouncycastle. Please add all the JARs under `oci-hdfs/third-party/lib` to the `spark.jars` config along with `oci-hdfs-full-*-jar` . Example :

```
SparkSession.builder.config("spark.jars", "/Users/xxxx/oci-hdfs/lib/oci-hdfs-full-2.9.2.1.jar,/Users/xxxx/oci-hdfs/third-party/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.68.jar,...)
```